# KeyError: "[''] not in index" - pandas boxplot

Tags: python, pandas

Here is what my pandas.dataframe looks like:

```py
    Own contribution assessment 1   Own contribution assessment 2   Own contribution assessment 3
0   40.0    40.0    40
1   50.0    40.0    40
2   75.0    75.0    75
3   33.0    33.0    33
4   25.0    25.0    25
```

When I do:

```py
df.boxplot(
        column=["Own contribution assessment 1", "Own contribution assessment 2", "Own contribution assessment 3"]
    )
```

I get the following error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3251, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-7-97700765dd5a>", line 1, in <module>
    df.head(5).boxplot(
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py", line 516, in boxplot_frame
    return plot_backend.boxplot_frame(
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\boxplot.py", line 458, in boxplot_frame
    ax = boxplot(
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\boxplot.py", line 435, in boxplot
    data = data[columns]
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3810, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns._get_indexer_strict(key, "columns")[1]
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 6111, in _get_indexer_strict
    self._raise_if_missing(keyarr, indexer, axis_name)
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 6174, in _raise_if_missing
    raise KeyError(f"{not_found} not in index")
KeyError: "['Own contribution assessment 3'] not in index"
```

I'm using `Python 3.10.2` and `pandas==1.5.1`.

also, when I just do `df.boxplot()`, I only have the first two columns, but when I do `df.columns` the three columns appear:

```py
df.columns
Out[14]: 
Index(['Own contribution assessment 1', 'Own contribution assessment 2',
       'Own contribution assessment 3'],
      dtype='object')
```

Summary:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Converting the column to float solved it somehow.